# change the format of a TODO tag in comments

Tags: vb.net, formatting, visual-studio-2015, comments, todo

In **VB.net** I have recently discovered the use of `TODO` tags in comments. I was wandering if it is possible to change the format of these tags in **visual studio 2015**, like the IDE does with code. (E.g. change `TODO`'s to be bold or a different shade of green)